# Minimizing $2a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ given $4a + 3b + c = 7$

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima, 3d

**Problem:**  Find the minimum value of the expression $2a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ if the point $(a,b,c)$ lies on the plane $4a + 3b + c = 7$.

I couldn't get very far, but I do know how would I solve a simpler problem, i.e. minimizing $a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ as that would simply be the perpendicular distance from the origin to the plane. I tried re-writing the expression as

$$ (a^2 + b^2) + (a^2 + c^2) $$
In hopes of finding something. But here also nothing significant was achieved. Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: Hint C-S inequality

Comment: Oh, that was quick. Thanks.

Comment: @NN2 could you please check my solution (I only learnt the C-S Inequality today, and I do not have the answer to this question.)

Comment: This question is not about minimal-surfaces. If you don't know what they mean, please read the tags description before using it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint,

Let $f(a,b,c)=2a^2+b^2+c^2$ and $g(a,b,c)=4a+3b+c-7$ ,

Now consider $\nabla f=\lambda \nabla g$ with $g(a,b,c)=0$.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not familiar with multi-variable calculus at the moment.

Comment: @ShivanshJaiswal okay

Answer (score 1):

By application of Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality

$$ \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i ^2 \right)\left(  \sum_{i=1}^{n} b_i ^2 \right) \geq \left( \sum_{i=1} a_i b_i \right)^2$$

We have
$$ (2a^2 + b^2 + c^2)((4/\sqrt{2})^2 + 3^2 + 1^2) \geq ((4/\sqrt{2} (\sqrt{2}a)+3b+c)^2 $$
$$ (2a^2 + b^2 + c^2)(18) \geq (4a+3b+c)^2 $$
$$ 2a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \geq 49/18 $$

Hence the minimum value of the given expression is $49/18$.

Comment: No, if you do that, you cannot get the equality. You should rather do
$$\left(2a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \right) \left( \left(4 / \sqrt 2 \right)^2 + 3^2 + 1^2  \right)  \ge (\sqrt{2}a\cdot4/ \sqrt{2} + b\cdot 3 + c\cdot 1)^2 = 7^2$$
The equality occurs iff  $\frac{\sqrt{2}a}{4/\sqrt 2} = \frac{b}{3} = \frac{c}{1}$ and $4a + 3b +c= 7$ , and you deduce easily $(a,b,c)$

Comment: Should I edit the fix into my answer?

Comment: You can of course.